# how to create popup message like gmail select option have using qtip in jquery?

Tags: css, html, jquery-plugins, qtip2

In the Gmail have select option

[image]

when we will click the arrow it will show a pop up message like all,none,read.
how to create the pop up message like this using qtip in jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Here how it's done using bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```